# Fetch content from the page behind the login page failed

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch the content from the page which is under login.

I have already logged in via browser, and I can access page via browser with no problem.

But, when I wanted to do with curl or file_get_contents, I get the login page content.

Basically, It's redirecting to login page.

But, I don't know in-spite of logged in why I am getting this problem.

Please help.

Comment: Would be helpful if you post any code.

Comment: do you mean "under login 'protection'"?

Comment: http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/

Comment: You are logged in from your browser.  When you access a page with cURL, from the server's point of view it's a different session, you're getting the login page again.  You need to actually log in with cURL using the same session.

Comment: Dr. Dan link given by you doesn't work for me.
Basically, I am accessing remote url.

Answer (score 0):

You should use anyone cUrl-wrapper, which supports cookies and sessions. With this you should log in to the site by the first request, then grab cookies/session_id and use it in the second cUrl-request to get a target page. It's one of possible algorithms.

Another one is to peep cookies and session_id (ususally, it's saved in cookies) in Browser Console (Network Tab) and add it to headers in your curl-script.